# `cat somefile | cat` in powershell gives 10000 lines instead of 100

Tags: powershell

Can someone please explain my misunderstanding here?  `cat somefile | cat` is outputting **10000** lines instead of **100 lines**.  I'm used to the Unix behavior of pipes.  Here's a script to reproduce the problem (these need to be entered line-by-line at a PowerShell prompt):

```bsh
seq 1 100 > somefile
cat somefile  # works as expected, outputs 100 lines
cat somefile | Measure-Object  # 100 lines, expected.
cat somefile | cat  # OUTPUTS 10000 lines!!!
# wait did I really just see that
cat somefile | cat | Measure-Object
# 10000 lines??!!!
cat somefile | cat | cat | Measure-Object
# 57300 lines???  That's not even a pattern!
```

So clearly I have no idea what's going on here.  I expected bash behavior.  I know it's not useful to do `cat somefile | cat`, but this is still surprising.

Bash behavior would be `cat somefile | cat | cat | cat` always gives exactly the same content as just `cat somefile`.

Comment: So you are surprised that Powershell does not show bash behaviour? What would be the bash behaviour?

Comment: Good question @Olaf.  I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: OK, I'm not completly sure but I'd explain it this way: Because [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1) takes a path as pipeline input and outputs a path you get a kind of recursive call for the same file.

Comment: Is it that each line of the output is associated with a file, so get-content grabs the file attribute of each line and pain ensues?

Comment: That's how I thought - yes. But I'm far away from beeing an expert.  ;-)

Comment: Bizarre, there is some kind of pattern, but I can't put my finger on what it is, for a fixed line count there's some polynomial that tells you how many lines there will be after n cats, I'm too dumb to see what the general rule for l lines is.. I also get different numbers than you for your example btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alias `cat` for `Get-Content` was introduced for convenience reasons I assume (to make Unix users feel more comfortable with PowerShell). That doesn't make `Get-Content` behave exactly like the Unix command `cat`, though. The cmdlet specifically does not echo string input from the pipeline:

```
PS C:\Temp> 'foo' | cat
cat : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either
because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties
do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:9
+ 'foo' | cat
+         ~~~
```

That is what `Write-Output` (or its alias `echo`) is for:

```
PS C:\Temp> 'foo' | Write-Output
foo
```

The default parameters of `Get-Content` that accept pipeline input are `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` respectively, both of which expect a valid path.

Upon closer inspection of the output of `Get-Content` you'll notice that the objects have not only the usual properties of string objects, but also some properties with information about the file from which the data was read, specifically `PSPath`:

```
PS C:\Temp> 4..6 > out.txt
PS C:\Temp> cat .\out.txt
4
5
6
PS C:\Temp> cat .\out.txt | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
...
PSChildName      NoteProperty          string PSChildName=out.txt
PSDrive          NoteProperty          PSDriveInfo PSDrive=C
PSParentPath     NoteProperty          string PSParentPath=C:\Temp
PSPath           NoteProperty          string PSPath=C:\Temp\out.txt
PSProvider       NoteProperty          ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
ReadCount        NoteProperty          long ReadCount=1
Chars            ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}
Length           Property              int Length {get;}
```

The `PSPath` property is what serves as the input for the second `Get-Content`, causing each line from the input file to trigger another `Get-Content` of the same file. However, the output objects from the first `Get-Content` have a property `ReadCount` as well (indicating the number of lines that have already been read from the file), which also happens to be a parameter of `Get-Content`. Because of that the second `Get-Content` doesn't read the input file *exactly* the same way as the first one. With `ReadCount=2` 2 lines from the file are read at a time, with `ReadCount=3` of 3 lines are read at a time, and so on.

```
PS C:\Temp> cat .\out.txt | cat
4   # ← input line 1 ("4"), ReadCount = 1, 1st read (returns "4")
5   # ← input line 1 ("4"), ReadCount = 1, 2nd read (returns "5")
6   # ← input line 1 ("4"), ReadCount = 1, 3rd read (returns "6")
4   # ← input line 2 ("5"), ReadCount = 2, 1st read (returns "4", "5")
5
6   # ← input line 2 ("5"), ReadCount = 2, 2nd read (returns "6")
4   # ← input line 3 ("6"), ReadCount = 3, 1st read (returns "4", "5", "6")
5
6
```

Because of that additional pipeline steps (`cat .\out.txt | cat | cat ...`) don't produce n<sup>m</sup> output lines (`n` being the number of lines in the file and `m` the number of pipeline steps).

Comment: What do you make of that when I do the steps in the question that I don't get 10000 = 100 * 100 lines but instead 573 lines? With what you're proposing, a further cat should produce 10000 * 10000 lines no?

Comment: This is a beautiful answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can't explain exactly why, but here is some dig.

First `cat` a file to a variable, assume the file content is `1..10`

```
$t = cat .\somefile # 1..10
```

Look into the first element's object properties, we will see a property `ReadCount`,

```
# $t | gm
$t[0].ReadCount # 1
$t[1].ReadCount # 2
$t[2].ReadCount # 3
# ...
```

Look into the source code of `Get-Content` or `cat`

[image]

So, I think the story is, for each element in `$t`, e.g. `$t[2] # 3` pipeline to `cat`, `cat` set `ReadCount` from the pipeline and read the file again imply the following command.

```
cat -Path .\somefile -ReadCount 3
```

For next `$t[3]`, `ReadCount` is 4, `cat` imply similar command

```
cat -Path .\somefile -ReadCount 4
```

On windows PowerShell, for a file `1..100`, we can get the line count is 57300, but `measure` list 2008 objects (because `measure-object` counts objects number, not line number).

```
cat .\somefile | cat | cat |measure
Count    : 2008
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
@((cat .\somefile | cat | cat)  | %{$_}).count
57300
```

So, my guess is right i think.